# How to trigger an alert when a binary file is created in a path on an Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics

I have got an Azure VM which is connected to a log analytics workspace. A third party application (no control on its behavior) is running on the vm and creates a binary file in a folder (like d:\app\bin) in specific circumstances. I would like to raise an alert once that file is created using Azure Monitor.

So, my specific question is if it is possible to watch a path on Azure VM for existence of a file and as soon as it is created, fire alert. Any idea if this is doable at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if someone else is after this, touched based with MS support and possible solution can be:

Use Change Tracking from Azure Automation , references are as below:

- Change Tracking: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking/overview
- Configure file tracking on Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking/manage-change-tracking#configure-file-tracking-on-windows
- Create alerts : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking/configure-alerts